# Which gear should I use to climb a steep hill?

Tags: toyota, shifting, corolla

I have a 1999 Toyota Corolla, which has a D, 2, and L gear.  I also have a steep driveway to climb everyday.  Which of these gears is most appropriate for going up steep inclines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have no faults with your transmission, it doesn't matter - an automatic transmission will automatically switch down  gear as and when it needs to. All the '2' gear does is not let you go over 2nd gear - which if you were heading downhill could make your engine over-rev...generally not recommended.

So D should be just fine.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a 4 cylinder or 6 cylinder engine?

Comment: No. Automatic transmissions are designed to use the most appropriate gear where possible. It doesn't matter what type of engine you have.

Answer (score 3):

If you're carrying a high load, L is best.

The gears work as follows:
D = use whichever gear the computer decides/ Useful for everyday driving.
2 = use first or second, depending on speed. Useful when carrying high loads at low speeds.
L = stay in the lowest gear. Best for carrying high loads up steep inclines.